# concat column values to one line in Vertica SQL

Tags: sql, database, string-concatenation, vertica

Example table:

```
id      some_column
1        value1
2        value2
2        value3
3        value4
1        value5
```

Expected result:

```
id some_column
1  value1, value5
2  value2, value3
3  value4
```

I tried `select id, concat(some_column) from table_name group by id`

It says concat does not exist or permission denied...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I want to use concat function. Why to install separate library. Concat exist in vertica if manually check. I just got the error. Am referring to correct the error or find the cause of it.

Comment: `concat()` is not an aggregate function.

Comment: it is: check `select CONCAT('this', ' YES')`

Comment: And https://github.com/vertica/Vertica-Extension-Packages/tree/master/strings_package how to install this. My Vertia SQL workbench is in Windows, and this readme doesnt guide how to integrate in existing one. Also how to use group_concat for the above example I mentioned?

Comment: That's concatenation, not aggregation. Aggregation is e.g. `sum()`, or `avg()`. `concat()` is ***not*** an _aggregate_ function.

Comment: ok got it. So what is aggregation function for my case. I would prefer easiest one like SUM. Just one word function.

Comment: See more options using leg and lead functiin her https://community.dev.hpe.com/t5/Vertica-Forum/Combine-Multiple-ROWS-into-single-row/td-p/222505/highlight/true/page/2

Comment: @elirevach Well lead function is like manually writing all column values. Then will group them. Whats the use if it can't select values from column automatically and aggregate?